The default counter app won't work in an Android Emulator
Macbook M1 chip
macOS Sonoma 14.4.1  

--
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

When I create a new flutter project, I can't get the default counter app to work: when I click on the + button, the count text doesn't increment.  I've tried creating a new flutter project in both Android Studio and VS Code, but when I select the Android Emulator the + button doesn't increment the counter text.  I can change other text in the app, then hot reload (by saving the file), and the text in the app changes, but the + button still won't increment the counter text.
On the other hand, if I select the iOS Simulator the + button does increment the counter text for new flutter projects created in both Android Studio and VS Code.
Initially, the Android Emulator was crashing in Android Studio, but I followed some advice on StackOverflow here, and that fix successfully launched the Android Emulator in a separate window.  After I did that yesterday, the default counter app worked fine in Android Studio using the Android Emulator.  Today, the default counter app doesn't work anymore.  I've tried creating additional new flutter projects in both Android Studio and VS Code, but when I select the Android Emulator, the + button in the default counter app does not increment the counter text.
The Android Emulator is:
Pixel 3a API 34 extension level 7 arm64-v8a
I am working on the codelab for the Namer App in Flutter's Write Your First Flutter App, and in Android Studio I can choose the Android Emulator, and the Namer App runs fine: I can click on the buttons and they do what I expect.
Edit: =====
I deleted all the new projects I created in both Android Studio and VS Code while I was trying to get the default counter app to work (which were in different directories), then I created a new project in Android Studio, chose the Android Emulator, clicked on the Run button, waited for the default counter app to launch, and now the + button works!
